# Why can I not download a file larger than 1.0 GB using my browser?

Tags: browser

I have attempted to download a 2.5 GB ZIP backup file from my hosting provider and the size of the resultant downloaded file is always around 1.0 GB.  The download just stops.  I see no errors displayed.  The file is, of course, corrupt since it did not finish loading.  I have used the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome and IE with the same result.  My hosting provider and my ISP state they do not place any limits on the size of downloaded files.  I have downloaded this size file using this machine from the same hosting provider for the past 3 years with no problems.  The last time I performed this download was in December of 2014 (worked fine).

I am running an Apache server on my WIN7 machine so I used the following script to see if I can simulate the problem locally (all files are located on the same computer).  The same results were observed (size limited to around 1.0 GB) so it can't be my hosting provider or my ISP.

```
<?php
// The source file backup-tue-mar-24-14_38_34-2015.zip is 2,488,232 KB
// The destination file george.zip will be anywhere from 721,771 KB to 1,033,857 KB

$file = 'D:\My_Backup\2015-03-22\backup-tue-mar-24-14_38_34-2015.zip';

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='. "george.zip");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

$file_handle = fopen($file, "r") or exit("Unable to open file ($file)");

while (!feof($file_handle)) {
  $line = fgets($file_handle, 16384);
  echo $line;
}

 ?>
```

**I used SFTP to download the same file from my hosting provider and it downloaded properly.**

I am running the latest version of WIN7 with an Intel i7 CPU (64 bit) with 12.0 GB of RAM.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: How long does this transfer take? Could you be running up against PHP's execution time limit?

Comment: When running local, the transfer takes a few seconds.  An error would be generated if PHP's execution limit was reached.  The PHP script is just to show how I simulated the problem.